# Is WUBI free to download?

Tags: wubi

Is WUBI freely available? I checked the link to download WUBI and the only way to proceed is by giving some amount as donation. I will surely do it, but I don't have a Paypal account and I am in urgent need to install Ubuntu. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why you go for wubi? Windows with UEFI firmware won't support wubi. Install Ubuntu on your HDD and make it dualboot with Windows.

Comment: Hmm I remember there to be a "skip this" option.

Comment: Indeed. Even by toggling all donation sliders to zero the user must always provide PayPal credentials to download the installer.

Comment: wubi is free !! for installing visit the site (http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Summary

Wubi is [definitely free](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#What_is_the_license.3F), although it hasn't yet (as of 2014-04-20) been updated for [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

The best place to download Wubi for the old Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is from [releases.ubuntu.com/12.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) ([wubi.exe direct link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe)).

---

### Detail

A bug was introduced on April 10th when we released changes to the [Ubuntu.com download section](http://www.ubuntu.com/download), which both hid the "skip" link on the Wubi contributions page, forcing you through Paypal, and broke the Wubi thank-you page so even if you did pay the download wouldn't start - pretty catastrophic. This is what led to the confusion.

I've now redirected the [Wubi contribute URL](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?distro=wubi&bits=&release=lts) directly to [the download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe). <strike>Now if you click "Get the installer" on the [Windows Installer page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer), your Wubi download will start immediately, so you never see the contributions page and don't even have the option to pay.</strike>

**Edit**: Now that Ubuntu 14.04 is out, the [old Windows Installer URL](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) on ubuntu.com now redirects you to the [main desktop download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), as Wubi has not been updated for the new Ubuntu 14.04 yet.

I've answered and closed [@JorgeCastro's bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content/+bug/1305971/).

Answer (score 5):

<del>There is a skip option if you don't want to donate.</del>

Apparently the skip button is not showing on the Wubi download page, possibly a bug as other download pages have the skip option.

You can download it from [the 12.04 page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/)

However, please remember:

- WUBI was dropped after 12.10, so no support will be available.
- WUBI doesn't support UEFI / win 8.

Comment: where? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?distro=wubi&bits=&release=lts I don't see one :D

Comment: OMG.. I don't see, either.. may be it is time to update the website.

Comment: You are right, because of some bug (issue) the skip option is not being shown. (Initially, I thought that was a rude way of asking for donations, but bugs are the signs that we human make code. :) )

Comment: Wow, that's a subtle bug! Nice work everyone, I've reported it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content/+bug/1305971

Comment: WUBI was dropped after 12.10 not 12.04..

Comment: @JorgeCastro thanks for filing the bug - I've responded and closed it with a sort of fix. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded it from this link:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

It should work

Comment: This page will probably disappear on Thursday 17th April (next week)

Comment: Well hopefully rather than disappearing it'll actually be redirected somewhere sensible.